# Preventing Spigot Watchdog Thread from stopping Server

Tags: java, plugins, crash, minecraft

I'm programming a new Spigot Plugin because I want to learn some new stuff. I'm trying to place a few thousand blocks by my plugin (it has a reason that I do that I know it sounds dumb), but the problem is that after a few seconds the Server stops working because the Server is not responding. It's not a problem for me that the server is not responding at the moment, but it is one for Spigot Watchdog Thread. It thinks that the server crashed and stops the server. I tried to place the blocks asynchronously, so the server keeps running, but Spigot doesn't allow me to do that and drops an error if I try to do that. Is there a way to prevent Spigot Watchdog Thread from stopping my server because of not responding? Or is there any other solution to place this many blocks?

Error Logs:

Synchronous Task:
https://hastebin.com/fogixamefe.yaml

Asynchronous Task:
https://hastebin.com/pumucozula.properties

Comment: Can you add your code in your question ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `max-tick-time` to `-1` in `server.properties`.

This should disable the watchdog entirely.

---

If you want to place that many blocks without catching a lag, you could delay placing blocks using `runTaskLater()`. For example:

```java
// this will place 10 blocks each tick for next 1000 ticks

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        placeNextBlock();
      }
    }
  }, i);
}
```

---

You can't place blocks in asynchronous tasks, because of Minecraft's server limitations.